# Error using Google distance matrix API with Python

Tags: python, google-maps-api-2

This is my code:

```
from googlemaps import Client as GoogleMaps
mapServices = GoogleMaps('')
start = 'texarkana'
end   = 'atlanta'
direction = mapServices.directions(start, end)
for step in direction['Direction']['Routes'][0]['Steps']:
    print(step['descriptionHtml'])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\directions.py", line 7, in <module>
for step in direction['Direction']['Routes'][0]['Steps']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: So what do you think is wrong here?

Comment: i dont know why the error is comming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would not be able to help you to directly pinpoint the error as I do not have an API key to try it for myself. However, I can give you some things that you can try and consider to find the root of the problem.

It seems that one of the indexes in your for loop (`for step in direction['Direction']['Routes'][0]['Steps']:`) is supposed to be an integer.

You can try to find out which using the built-in `type()` function. So to debug, I would try: `type(direction)`, then `type(direction['Direction'])` and so on with the exception of `direction['Direction']['Routes']` as that is already a list.

I suggest you use the interactive python interpreter for this. The one you would be looking for is when you enter your code (e.g. `type(direction)`) you get `type<'list'>`.

After finding out which is the culprit, perhaps you can index through it and find the one you want or read the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start).

Comment: can you please explain in detail because I tried but nothing happened

Comment: @RishavGupta Nothing is supposed to happen. This is just a debugging method. Use the python interpreter to find out which part of your `direction['Direction']['Routes'][0]['Steps']` is wrong.